# .NET Dock Panel?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

Trying to find a dock panel/window widget like Visual Studio uses for its Toolbox/Properties/Solution Explorer/etc windows.  Is there seriously not one already part of the .net framework? Or am I blind? If not, is there one you can recommend for me to download?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Weifenluo's [DockPanel Suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/) is a *very* popular implementation of the Visual Studio style user interface.  It has the right price too.

Comment: I deleted my own post and am throwing my support to you.  Good link.  Thank you!  +1.

Comment: I stumbled across this too, but I'm trying to figure out how to use the darn thing.

Comment: Ah -- this is a good start: http://robertsmyth.blogspot.com/2008/06/programmatic-pane-nesting-using.html

Comment: There's a better way to set dock-right, and that tutorial doesn't show you how to add content to the panels. Thus, a code snippet on my blog: http://programanddesign.com/uncategorized/net-dock-panel/

Answer (score 3):

You can use Visual Studio (2008) Shell itself as a framework for your own apps:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx2008/products/bb933751.aspx

This should give you all the docking, etc. that VS has.

*Edit:  I don't know if the shell will be available for VS 2010

Answer (score 3):

I dont think you will find one in the controls included by default in VS, but I have used the Telerik version for ASP.NET and been impressed.

[Telerik Dock control](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/dock.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is an old question I thought I'd just add [AvalonDock](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/) to list list, for anyone stumbling in here with the same question.

It's a very powerful framework, it's actively developed and it's free.

Comment: Just in case someone comes here looking for a WinForms package, it might be helpful to know that AvalonDock provides controls for WPF only.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one with the framework, but there a bunch you can buy.  I like [Actipro's](http://actiprosoftware.com).  I also suspect there are some free ones if you hunt around, but I haven't tried any of them.