# Show multiple windows form into a single form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have three windows forms like below images. I want to combine all three forms into one form. Which I can show fullscreen application as a one window

[image]

I can't use only one form with all the code. It has to be something like this three forms combined into one full-screen form. Is there a way to combine them?

Comment: You realize your last sentence doesn't make any sense, right?  It's either one form or it isn't.  What you probably want is MDI docking.  Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8770228/102937

Comment: I think you might want to switch your 3 existing Forms to a UserControl?

Comment: I will read it. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean lokusking?

Comment: Take a look on MDI docking.

Comment: [Creating MDI application using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7571/Creating-MDI-application-using-C-Walkthrough)

Comment: I updated my code. It's not working

Comment: I would recommend dock panels over MDI for your scenario.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060364/net-dock-panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by `MDI Container`

```
FormA formA = new FormA();
formA.IsMDIContainer = true;

FormB formB = new FormB();
formB.MDIParent = formA;
formB.Show();

FormC formC = new FormC();
formC.MDIParent = formA;
formC.Show();
```

and then run

```
formA.Show();
```

look at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3553/Introduction-to-MDI-Forms-with-C)

Comment: I tried this but it doesnt give me any error and doesnt even open any form. I will update my code with what I did.

Comment: try my update, and see details in the link

Comment: It shows now. but check my new image

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3553/Introduction-to-MDI-Forms-with-C this article show how can you position them, its long process not wise to put in a answer so if you try this way you will get your desire output I hope